# in remote X11: xclock works but gitk or git gui do not

Tags: crash, tcl, x11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xming

I installed a X server on Windows 10, I used the WSL and I noticed an issue

```
# echo $DISPLAY
localhost:0
```

When I run xclock or xcalc everything works fine, but when I run gitk I get a segfault

```
~ # xclock
Warning: Cannot convert string "" to type XftFont
~ # gitk
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
~ #
```

Is there an issue with this?

I'm using OpenSuse Leap 15.1.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try any other distribution?

Comment: You might be missing fonts, or the standard Xft font configuration file.

Comment: @Biswapriyo On Ubuntu it works fine ... any ideas?

Comment: @DonalFellows It might not be necessarily that problem since it works on Ubuntu. Maybe the tk library was built using some weird fonts?